# Django unittest self.assertTemplateUsed, how to check the occurrence of multiple templates

Tags: python, django, django-unittest

```
self.assertTemplateUsed(response,('goods/item_list.html', 'base.html', 'inc/_nav.html') ,)
```

error

> AssertionError: False is not true : Template '('goods/item_list.html',
> 'base.html', 'inc/_nav.html')' was not a template used to render the
> response. Actual template(s) used: goods/items_list.html, base.html,
> inc/_nav.html

how to check for multiple templates in response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use three method calls:

```
self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'goods/items_list.html')
self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'base.html')
self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'inc/_nav.html')
```

Or you can work with an iterable, and enumerate over that iterable:

```
for template in ('goods/items_list.html', 'base.html', 'inc/_nav.html'):
    self.assertTemplateUsed(response, template)
```